# windows form c# while loop with double variables

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

currently working on this assignment with a couple classmates http://pdfsr.com/pdf/loopexercise.pdf
and having difficulty with the structure of the while loop with the if-else statements. Here is what I currently have under the 'go'button event handler.

```
private void Go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double startnum = Double.Parse(start.Text);
    double endnum = Double.Parse(end.Text);
    double sumOdd = 0;
    double sumEven = 0;
    double product = 0;
    double allSum = 0;
    double Ecount = 0;
    double Ocount = 0;
    double average = 0;
    while (startnum != endnum)
    {
        {
            if (IsOdd(startnum))
            {
                sumOdd += startnum;
                Ocount++;
            }
            else
            {
                sumEven += startnum;
                Ecount++;
            }
            allSum += startnum;
            product *= startnum;
            startnum++;
        }
```

Comment: Nobody here is likely to bother reading through your assignment and completing it for you. Instead, you should state the specific issue you are having with the code above, what you are expecting/intending it to do instead, and what you have tried to solve it.

Comment: State the specific problem you are experiencing

Comment: Try putting if statement that start.Text and end.Text exist if it is empty, also output the answer to check if your loop is correct.

Comment: yes i appreciate the feedback. The question i currently have, is if the current structure of my while loop, declaring of the double variables, and if-else statement is correct/ on the right track? Thanks

Comment: @Maninder-singh-Saini why have you got a second { underneath the while loop?

Comment: You were probably meant to fail at this assignment.  Teaches you that floating point math does not behave mathematical rules.  A value like 0.1 is neither odd nor even, operators like == and != may never be true.  Talk to your teacher about this, pay attention in class, don't do drugs.

Comment: the reason behind second { is that, i am about to proceed in the program but not sure i got it right untill now.

Comment: Passant thanks for your concern bud

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work out for that part

```
        while (start <= end)
        {

            if (oddNum(start))
            {
                oddSum += start;
                oddCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                evenSum += start;
                evenCount++;
            }
            totalSum += start;
            productNum *= start;
            avrgNum = totalSum / end;
            avrgSum = avrgNum / totalSum;
            start++;
         }
```